# How do I make the python bempp package work in google colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use the bempp-cl package to do Boundary Element Method work. When I pip install it all there are no problems but when I try to use bempp.api I keep getting the following error.

> CalledProcessError: Command '/usr/local/bin/gmsh -2 /tmp/tmpwkpa7qtg/tmpnsv6qtuv.geo' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Has anyone got bempp to work?

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is either you don't have the gmsh binary installed (only the python api) or it's been installed in the wrong location. In either case you can fix it by running a cell with:

```
!apt-get install gmsh
!rm /usr/local/bin/gmsh
!ln -s /usr/bin/gmsh /usr/local/bin/
```

There might be some issues however, because the gmsh version in the Ubuntu repositories is fairly out of date, as colab is currently running 18.04 LTS. If you run into those you can compile a more current version from the gmsh gitlab or use a more recent build from conda.